# Broken pipe error?

Tags: bash

There's surely a simple explanation, but I've got this custom function in my .bashrc which is throwing a Broken Pipe error:

```
function log {
        if [ $# -eq 1 ]
        then
                svn log -q $1 | head
        elif [ $# -eq 2 ]
        then
                svn log -q $1 | head -n $2
        fi
}
```

Now when I call the function with `log test.py 5` for instance, I get the desired result, but also the message: `svn: Write error: Broken pipe` afterwards.  Help is appreciated.

Comment: Because after a while `head` has had enough to do its job so just terminates - pipe closed!

Comment: It is nothing you should worry about, just broken svn behavior. Read this answer for more info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60228/

Comment: `head` stops reading as soon as it finishes its job and terminates. That kills its end of the pipe. svn notices that when it tries to keep writing and complains.

Comment: You could perhaps do `svn log -q $1 2>> /dev/null | head -n $2`. But that might occasionally hide other errors you would prefer to see....

Comment: Thanks everyone, knew it would be simple. @twalberg, that sounds like a good solution for what I need. I don't expect to have many errors with this command, and I'll just remember that I've muted them.

Comment: @twalberg What's the point of `2>>/dev/null`? It's not like appending to `/dev/null` will preserve what's already in there. `2>/dev/null` is enough, and that's idiomatic.

Comment: @4ae1e1 It's a habit I got into with a shell once that refused to honor `2> /dev/null` because some shell option was set to avoid overwriting existing files, and it didn't properly understand device nodes or symlinks. I think it was an older version of `ksh`, but I don't remember now. You're right that it's unnecessary probably in most modern shells, but it's not harmful, either... Either syntax will work.

Comment: @twalberg Yeah, that sounds like Korn shell... I don't have much experience with it, but even today Zsh has a `CLOBBER` option to mimic that behavior, and I'm aware of that. Anyway, it still won't bark on `>/dev/null`. I guess I'm too young...

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do `svn log -q $1 2>> /dev/null | head -n $2`. But that might occasionally hide other errors you would prefer to see.... – twalberg